# Storing the o/p of Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am new to java..... I have 3 files in the zip folder, which I m extracting it using

```
String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"jar -xvf record.zip\"";
     Process ps= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I need to store all the three files present in record.zip into a String after extracting 
these files using jar -xvf

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream())); 
     String temp = br.readLine();
     while( temp != null ) { //!temp.equals(null)) {
         output.write(temp);
         temp = br.readLine();
         }
         output.close();
```

I tried this code but it doesn't fetch me the desired result....
Thanks in advance....

Comment: 1) Implement ***all*** the recommendations of the Java World article linked from the [exec info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) 2) Once you've done that, you should have either solved the problem or have enough information for others to help you solve it.  3) ..then split the commands up into a `String[]` & 4) Use `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: 1) You need to break your command down into a `String[]`. 2) unzip doesn't output the contents of the files to `stdout` so you cannot read them from there - you would have to read the file names from there and then read the files. 3) I would recommend you use the [functionality already in the JDK](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm).

Comment: OH, BTW - the J2SE has [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) & related classes.  Why use a (broken, platform specific) `Process` for this?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson ....yup we can extract these zip file using util.zip package...but according to my requirement need to extract it using Xvf

Comment: @user2181047 - why would you have that requirement?

Comment: The more I look at that code, the sillier it seems.  This code has to run on a system with a JDK? *"need to extract it using Xvf"*  Using those options to the Jar tool?  So what?  Those options could be implemented in Java code quite easily.

Comment: @jtahlborn.....coz I wana know/learn different approach to solve the same problem ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functionality already in the JDK to read from zip files, for example this will print the contents of all files in a zip to the console line by line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ZipException, IOException {
    final File file = new File("myZipFile.zip");
    final ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
    final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        final ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println(entry);
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipFile.getInputStream(entry)));
            for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
    zipFile.close();
}
```

Comment: @ bmorris ....ya we can but what if the file format is not zip.Assume its .sysplan file format....it would be difficult to extract content of .sysplan file.Thats the reason I m focusing on Generic mehod to extract compressed file.........

Comment: @user2181047 from [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.hardware.ibm.midrange/122256) it would seem that "The sysplan is really just a zip file.". I don't see any problem with reading a `.sysplan` file. Try it. The extension of the file does not matter as long as it is compressed using zip - your method is no more generic.